# Rake NoMethodError: undefined method 'scan' for Lexicon:Class

Tags: ruby, rake, nomethoderror

I am receiving a **NoMethodError: undefined method 'scan' for Lexicon:Class** when I try to run a rake test with the following RakeFile.

```
require './lib/ex48/lexicon.rb'
require 'test/unit'

class TestLexicon < Test::Unit::TestCase

    def test_directions
        assert_equal(Lexicon.scan('north'), [%w(direction north)])
    end

end
```

I have a simple Lexicon class:

```
class Lexicon

  def initialize
    @direction = %w(north south east west down up left right back)
    @verbs = %w(go stop kill eat)
    @stop_words = %w(the in of from at it)
    @nouns = %w(door bear princess cabinet)
    @numbers = (0..9)
  end

  attr_reader :direction, :verbs, :stop_words, :nouns, :numbers

  def scan(input)
    words = input.split
    result = []

    words.each do |word|
      if @direction.include? word
        result.push ['direction', word]
        next
      end

      if @verbs.include? word
        result.push ['verb', word]
        next
      end

      if @stop_words.include? word
        result.push ['stop', word]
        next
      end

      if @nouns.include? word
        result.push ['noun', word]
        next
      end

      result.push ['number', word] if @numbers.include? word
    end

    result
  end

end
```

and I want to see if the scan method is working. I'm learning Ruby, so I am new to the language, and this is my second RakeFile test. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`def self.scan` in order to make the method a class one, not instance method(called on instances of a class). Or simply use `Lexicon.new(args).scan`

Comment: `self.scan` did not work, because I needed to initialize the instance variables. But, I was forgetting to instantiate Lexicon as you said. Doing `lexicon = Lexicon.new` and then calling each `Lexicon` as `lexicon` made the test successful. Thank you very much! Silly mistake on my part.

Comment: It's a bit strange how you use the constructor(initialize) - the data set in it is constant, it does not change from instance to another instance. I'd pull that into constants in the class Lexicon, and make the `scan` method a class one.

Comment: For future reference this OP questio originates from https://learnrubythehardway.org/book/ex48.html .