# NoMethodError: undefined method `scan' for Lexicon:Class

Tags: ruby

Totally stuck in ex48 of Learn Ruby The Hard Way. My test is:

```
require "lexicon.rb"
require "test/unit"

class TestLexicon < Test::Unit::TestCase
    def test_directions()
        assert_equal(Lexicon.scan("north"), [['direction', 'north']])
    end
end
```

I am supposed to write code that makes the test pass. I am asked to create a class `Lexicon` that has-a method `class`. I get the syntax of `assert_equal`. But I cannot comprehend what code I should write to get output `Lexicon.scan("north")`.

I have read [Rake NoMethodError: undefined method 'scan' for Lexicon:Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27729644/rake-nomethoderror-undefined-method-scan-for-lexiconclass) but it didn't help I am afraid. I have thought really hard for quite some time, I cannot wrap my head around it. Thanks!

Comment: Did you define `self.scan` in class `Lexicon`?

Comment: include all information related to the `lexicon.rb`